# WeldProxy doesn't recognize source on exception

Tags: java, wildfly, cdi, log4j2

I'm facing a strange issue in a Java 8 application which use Jax-RS, CDI and run on Wildfly 14.

I have this simple Controller class:

```
Path("/test")
public class TestController {
    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test(@Context SecurityContext request) {
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("properties.txt")) {
        System.getProperties().load(is);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }
        
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Calling test method will always throw an Exception because properties.txt doesn't exists and this is ok. The strange is that in the stack trace I have a lot of unknown source:

```
[ERROR] [/test/test] [rest.TestController] Error occurs
java.io.FileNotFoundException: properties.txt
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at com.testapp.rest.TestController.test(TestController.java:42) ~[classes:?]
**at com.testapp.rest.TestController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.test(Unknown Source) ~[classes:?]**
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
[...]
```

The bold line is the one I'm not understanding. Maybe is a Wildfly bad configuration?

By the way, my Jax-RS initializer is this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public JaxRsActivator() {
        LogFactory.useLog4J2Logging();
        
        classes.add(TestController.class);
    }   

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public HashSet<Class<?>> getClasses(){
      return classes;
    }
}
```

And this is my log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">${logDir}</Property>
        <Property name="messagePattern">[%-5level] %X{method}[%logger{2}] %msg</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${messagePattern}\n" />
        </Console>
        
        <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${basePath}/app.log" filePattern="${basePath}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${messagePattern}%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <Appender-ref ref="File" level="ERROR" />
            <Appender-ref ref="Console" level="ERROR" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.ibatis.io" level="ERROR">
            <Appender-ref ref="File" />
            <Appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <Appender-ref ref="File" level="ERROR" />
            <Appender-ref ref="Console" level="ERROR" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
    
</Configuration>
```

Comment: How is this log4j2 related and not weld? And why is the 'source' being unknown a problem? The real corresponding line of source code is one line above... Line 42 in the real implementation.

Comment: The container creates a proxy to your bean on the fly so there is no source for that.

Comment: I wanted to add an additional line to my comment but @Lini beat me too it.

Comment: Sorry, the example is too simple and not really useful. By the way I found where my issue came and it's not related to Weld but it was simply a fault in my Exception hierarchy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My "issue" with Weld it's not related with Weld but it's a fault in my Exception hierachy which cause a loss in stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of the comments above have the right answer: for whatever reason, Weld has seen fit to create a client proxy for your resource class.  Client proxy sources are not (as a rule) available.

Now, the real question is: why is Weld creating a client proxy for your resource class, given that it has no scope annotation on it, and therefore, you'd think, would be in `@Dependent` scope?  I'm going to *guess* that RestEasy, the JAX-RS implementation authored by Red Hat and, I assume, shipped as part of WildFly, makes unannotated resource classes `@RequestScoped` by default, rather than what Jersey does, which is most closely emulated by `@Dependent` scope.  And, most importantly: `@RequestScoped` objects are proxied.

Comment: Sorry, the example is too simple and not really useful. By the way I found where my issue came and it's not related to Weld but it was simply a fault in my Exception hierarchy.